# Interpretation for a condition in fluid dynamics

Tags: physics, mathematical-modeling, fluid-dynamics

I have been working with some mathematical models in biology and fluid mechanics. My problem is about
the interpretation of a condition that I found for a vector
representing the velocity of a fluid. The exact question is the next:

Let $\mathbf{u=(}u_{1},u_{2},u_{3})$ be a vector field representing the
velocity of a fluid. After making some accounts with models using partial
differential equations, I found that the matrix
\begin{equation}
-A:=\frac{1}{2}\left(  \frac{\partial u^{j}}{\partial x_{i}}+\frac{\partial
u^{i}}{\partial x_{j}}\right)  _{i,j=1,2,3}%
\
\end{equation}
should be positive definite. Does this condition has a physical interpretation
in fluid dynamics or tensors?

Any comment or reference will be highly appreciate!

Comment: In the fluids literature, the symmetric part of the velocity gradient is usually called the "rate of deformation tensor" or the "velocity strain" tensor. Your $A$ is the negative of that.

Comment: I would be highly suspicious of such a model. Biological fluids are usually close to incompressible. In that case the matrix A is traceless and therefore definitely NOT positive definite!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is the answer that you have been looking for, but let me offer a rather trivial observation.

Your tensor is the Lie derivative of the metric tensor with respect to the vector field $\textbf u$. Loosely speaking, the Lie derivative $\mathcal{L}_\textbf{u}$ has an interpretation as a derivative with respect to "dragging" a tensor along the flow defined by $\textbf{u}$. A simple manipulation shows that for any vector field $\textbf{v}$,
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}_\textbf{u} (\textbf{v} \cdot \textbf{v}) = 
2 \textbf{v} \cdot \mathcal{L}_\textbf{u} \textbf{v} - 2 \textbf{v} A \textbf{v} \,,
\end{equation}
where the matrix $A$ is the one you have defined. A flow $\textbf{u}$ with positive definite $(-A)$ has the property that
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}_\textbf{u} (| \textbf{v} |^2 ) \geq 
2 \textbf{v} \cdot \mathcal{L}_\textbf{u} \textbf{v}
\end{equation}
for any vector field $\textbf{v}$.

I hope this observation has some use to you.